# How to read selected Excel column

Tags: excel, vb.net, exceldatareader

Using the **ExcelDataReader** from http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com and this code:

```
Dim stream As FileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

'1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)
'...
'2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)
'...
'3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
Dim result As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()
'...
'4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = True
Dim result As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()

'5. Data Reader methods
While excelReader.Read()
    'excelReader.GetInt32(0);
End While

'6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close()
```

How to read selected excel column? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What do you mean by selected column?